# objects..better arrays?

Tags: php, oop

I was just reading through a tutorial and they mentioned that Objects in php are just the better way of arrays. I am confused? Can someone clear the concept for me.
thanks

Comment: would you provide the link to the tutorial for reference? I disagree generally since array provide a utility for one set of needs and objects for quite another but maybe some context will give me a better sense of the authors mindset.

Comment: http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/PHP-Classes-And-Objects%3A-A-Guide-To-Development

Comment: here is another one...different then what I was reading but confirming my doubts
http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was more or less true for PHP 4, where there was no actual encapsulation. In fact, objects provide some benefits over plain array:

- Encapsulation (`private` and `protected` members) – easier to preserve invariants.
- Inheritance – a type inherits the default behaviour of its superclass, you only have to replace the parts that differ.
- Dynamic dispatch (the method that's actually called depends on the type of variable) – provides decoupling of interface and implementation and abstraction.
- Less polution of global namespace with functions (less compelling since the introduction of namespaces in PHP 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

I would use arrays when I have a list of the same type of data. A group of integers, a group of strings etc. Objects represent something such as a person or a car. You might say well then just use a hash array. A hash array is not very object oriented. If I'm working with an array I assume it is all related data and I can foreach, pop, shift through the data. Working with an object hopefully I know that it represents a user, car engine or computer and I can ask it questions.